# Кодировка в xml запросе

Tags: xml, кодировка

Всем привет!
Возникла проблема в перекодировании данных из xml запроса.
Контрагент выслал на анализ кусок xml, но я не могу расшифровать кириллические данные (там точно кириллица).

```
<LastName>[0xca][0xc0][0xd0][0xd2][0xc0][0xc2][0xdb][0xc9]</LastName>
<FirstName>[0xc0][0xcd][0xc4][0xd0][0xc5][0xc9]</FirstName>
<SurName>[0xc2][0xc0][0xd1][0xc8][0xcb][0xdc][0xc5][0xc2][0xc8][0xd7]</SurName>
```

Что это за кодировка? Как ее прочитать? Как перевести в кириллицу?
Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/ для нахождения и перевода кодировок

Comment: нормально лебедевский декодер не расшифровывает.